# Image selected does not render in release version of app

Tags: flutter, dart, release

I developed an app using flutter, on the debug version of the app everything is working as it should, but when I test with the release version and I try to add an image from either camera or gallery the image will not show on the `Image.file` `Widget` I am using to render it. but this same process worked well on the debug. I have added  permissions to the `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest` file which is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but nothing seems to work.

```
  Widget cameraPhoto() {
    return Consumer<HouseHoldViewModel>(builder: (context, vm, _) {
     
      return vm.savedImage.file != null && vm.savedImage.file.toString().isNotEmpty
          ? ClipOval(
    child:
         Image.file(
      vm.savedImage.file,
      height: 86,
      width: 86,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
  ): Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: vm.pictureUrl != null &&
                                  vm.pictureUrl.isNotEmpty
                              ? CachedNetworkImageProvider(vm.pictureUrl)
                              : ExactAssetImage('assets/profile_holder.png'))))
           ;
    });
  }
```

This is the method that should handles displaying of the image after i have picked the image using `Image picker`

```
void _bottomModal() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
            height: 100,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Consumer<HouseHoldViewModel>(
                    builder: (context, vm, _) => GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => _pickImage(vm, ImageSource.camera),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(S.of(context).takeAPicture)
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Consumer<HouseHoldViewModel>(
                    builder: (context, vm, _) => GestureDetector(
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(S.of(context).chooseFromGallery)
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () => _pickImage(vm, ImageSource.gallery),
                        ))
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  void _pickImage(HouseHoldViewModel vm, ImageSource source) async {
    var selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    vm.setSavedImage = selected;
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Since it is working fine on the debug version of my app why is the release not working. Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: The image is not been updated to the image.file widget

Comment: @ChidinmaEkenne might that have something to do with the fact that you didn't call `notifyListeners` after `vm.setSavedImage = selected;` in the `pickImage()`

Comment: I have a viewmodel Class that calls the notifyListeners. so this is the mehod :` set setSavedImage(File value) {
    _savedImage = value.toString().isNotEmpty
        ? FileValidationModel(value, null)
        : FileValidationModel(null, null);

    notifyListeners();
  }`